# How can I pass select field ID and its value to ajax without having any form?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a select field which has ID name as 'region_code' well as its value. And I want pass ID in ajax. As you can see below, the input field is not included in any form. It has a value and the ID

**Is it possible to get value in ajax as shown below?**

```
  echo '<select id="region_code" onchange="show_region_code();">';

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT region_code, region_name FROM list_region");
  while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {                      
             echo "<option value=\"$rows[0]\">".$rows["1"].'</option>';
  }
  echo '</select>';
```

**My ajax function as below**

```
function show_region_code() {

     var region_code = $("#region_code").val();

     $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "show_region_code.php",
            data: { region_code1: region_code },
              success: function(data) {
                     $("#region_code").html(data);
            }
     });
 }
```

Comment: so the question is, is it possible? yes.

Comment: I think your code should work. What problem are you having with it?

Comment: try changing this line 
echo '<select id="region_code"  
  onchange="show_region_code(document.region.region_code.value);">'; to 
echo '<select id="region_code"  
  onchange="show_region_code();">';

Comment: @AjayChauhan Isn't that what he has? I think you need to refresh, he made that change more than 5 minutes ago.

Comment: The calling function says <select id="region_code" onchange="show_region_code();">

Comment: @Barmar: Then he could just pass the parameter in his javascript function and get the value why use the line 'var region_code = $("#region_code").val();'

Comment: @user3766078 : Please check the calling line you are passing a value to the function. The line is as follows
echo '<select id="region_code"  
  onchange="show_region_code(document.region.region_code.value);">';

Comment: no need of passing any thing. his code is working.i seemply did this:

Comment: you can use this function show_region_code(Obj) { alert(Obj.value); } if you are following Mayank Sharma code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this**

```
<select id="region_code" onchange="show_region_code(this);">
    <option value="1">te</option>
    <option value="2">te2</option>
</select>

function show_region_code(Obj)
{
    alert(Obj.id);
}
```

Comment: It worked for me, but I couldn't get value itself. As per your answer I want like 1 or 2. Rather it gives me only literal meaning 'regional_code'.

Comment: user3766078 then you can use this function show_region_code(Obj)
{
alert(Obj.value);
}

Comment: Now complete package. This is it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

see this it's your code only and working:

```
<?php 
echo '<select id="region_code" onchange="show_region_code();">';
$rows=0;
  //$result = mysql_query("SELECT region_code, region_name FROM list_region");
  while($rows !=2) { 
    $rows++;
             echo "<option value=$rows>".$rows.'</option>';

  }
  echo '</select>';
?>
<script>
function show_region_code() {

     var region_code = $("#region_code").val();
alert(region_code);
     $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "show_region_code.php",
            data: { region_code1: region_code },
              success: function(data) {
                     $("#region_code").html(data);
            }
     });
 }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php         
   echo '<select id="region_code" onchange="show_region_code();">';

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT region_code, region_name FROM list_region");
   while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {                      
      echo "<option value=".$rows[0].">".$rows[1]."</option>";
   }
   echo '</select>';
?>

function show_region_code() {

     var region_code = $("#region_code").val();

     $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "show_region_code.php",
            data: "region_code1="+region_code,
            success: function(data) {
               $("#region_code").html(data);
            }
     });
 }
```